# How to create an architecture in Django which enables user-installable third-party plugin integration

Tags: python, django, plugins, architecture, system

## How to create an architecture in Django which enables user-installable third party plugin integration

**Problem**: We need to create a Django project which enables third-party developers to develop plugins. The Django application is just acting as a RestAPI/socket server for now and has a react application on the frontend. We certainly need to create some frontend hooks for the UI part for the plugin to be intractable.

**Other concerns**:
- We want to host the plugin ourselves by some kind of installation processes like copying files or running setup of some kind etc.
- We don't want the plugin to have direct access to the database
- We want the plugin to be an event driven code, ex: if the happens then some part of code will run
- We want the plugin to have their own data to be saved in our database
- We want the plugin to be safe on our system so that they can't access our system files
- We don't want plugin execution to slow our current process it should run in the background if possible.

**Our stack**:
- Django (with some part on django-channels)
- React (A PWA)
- Celery with Redis

**Our experience**: We are students with little or some experience with Django and React.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the plugin to provide background tasks runnable to celry and UI component that can be updatable by websocket right ? Aso when you say react (A PWD) do you mean a Progressive Web App, i.e PWA ?

Comment: Thanks for correcting I mistaken wrote PWD its PWA. But on the 1st point, I want a UI interface for plugins as well as code execution. The code execution will be in the background with celery so that the plugin doesn't interrupt the main processes.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer because I think it depends a lot on what you want to expose as extendable be the plugins and what should not, but look at [the tutorial for reusable app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/reusable-apps/) and [the django-plugin](https://pythonhosted.org/django-plugins/)